# python flask normal function to decoration

Tags: python, flask

I have this python `flask` code :

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(e):
    logg = open("server_log_404.txt", 'a')
    logg.write("\r\n\r\n========================\n")
    logg.write("%s\n" % datetime.datetime.today().ctime())
    logg.write("%s\n" % request.url )
    logg.write("%s" % request.headers)
    logg.write("%s\n" % str(request.form))
    logg.write("%s\n" % str(request.args))
    logg.close()
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

I need change function `logg` in decoration for logging more pages. I need function like this :

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
@make_logg
def not_found(e):
    return render_template('404.html'), 404
```

Is possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just transform it into a decorator:

```
from functools import wraps
def make_logg(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        logg = open("server_log_404.txt", 'a')
        logg.write("\r\n\r\n========================\n")
        logg.write("%s\n" % datetime.datetime.today().ctime())
        logg.write("%s\n" % request.url )
        logg.write("%s" % request.headers)
        logg.write("%s\n" % str(request.form))
        logg.write("%s\n" % str(request.args))
        logg.close()
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Maybe it will be necessary to use `functools.wraps` because Flask routing works with function name.

Comment: @selfmarket.net, try with this change, without using wraps im changing the name of the function

Comment: @pages.route('/contacts.html')
def contacts():
    return render_template('pages/contacts.html')